# Is there any way to easily select multiple messages in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Can you shift select or drag select to select a bunch of messages in Gmail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the same <kbd>Shift</kbd>+select to select a range and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+select to select multiples as you might expect in a desktop app.

A couple of other options:

- If the items you want to select can be narrowed down via a search, you could perform the search and then use the select all option.
- If not, you can achieve the outcome with [keyboard shortcuts](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6594). Use `j` and `k` to scroll vertically, and use `x` to select the conversation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can check the first checkbox in a range of messages, hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, click the last checkbox.